# Flutter - Order of execution inside Future.wait()

Tags: flutter, future

I have a login screen where If login is success, I want to execute two functions which resides in two separate provider classes.

```
if (isLoginSuccess == true) {
    Future.wait([
      context.read<UserProvider>().fetchUser(),
      context.read<LogProvider>().addLogData(actionId: 1),
      Future.delayed(
        const Duration(microseconds: 100),
      ),
    ]);
```

I want the code to execute in the order I called. But that is not happening. fetchUser() function assigns login id and I am using that id in addLogData to insert into another table.

Is my approach correct? Please correct where I am wrong.

Comment: You can await the first function and call the second after that. You need to be in an async function and to use the "await" keyword.

Comment: If you have a `List` of `Future`s and want to wait for them one at a time in sequence, then use [`Future.forEach`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/forEach.html).

Comment: @jamesdlin .. can you explain a bit about future.foreach or share any resource link?

Comment: @VincentDR.. I tried it already.. when I use await, it gives error.

Comment: @user19976096 You could do `await Future.forEach(listOfFutures, (future) => future)`.  Or using a normal `for` loop might be more straightforward: `for (var future in listOfFutures) { await future; }`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Sorry to bother you again... I didn't understand how to add my functions in a list? **Function 1. context.read<UserProvider>().fetchUser()** --> is inside UserProvider class that returns user id. **Function 2. context.read<LogProvider>().addLogData(actionId: 1)** --> is inside LogProvider class in which I insert a record in supabase table.  Function 2 executes before Function1.  Do you think there is a need of loop here. Only 2 functions. Second one should wait for the first one to complete.

Comment: Sorry, I was under the assumption that you needed a `List` of `Future`s because you needed to build it dynamically or something.  If it's just a fixed set of operations, you don't need a `List`.  Just `await` each `Future` separately.